# GL_NEAREST in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

If I use the fixed pipeline, I can use

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

to make an image 'pixelated' as opposed to fragments in between pixels in the image being interpolated. How would I do the same thing in GLSL program? I'm using the texture2D function. I ask because I am using a shader program for my skybox, and you can see the edges because the edge pixels get blurred with grey. This problem gets fixed if I were to use the fixed pipeline and the above function calls.

Comment: GLSL uses the same sampler states (wrap, filter, mipmap bias, etc.) as the fixed-function pipeline when you use `texture (...)`. This behavior you are describing sounds more like an issue with texture wrap mode, but that is just an educated guess at best, assuming that the other side of your image is grey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same texture minification and magnification filters with the programmable pipeline. It sounds like the issue is not the min/mag filter, but with how you're handling texture clamping/wrapping. Either that or your textures have gray in them, which you probably don't want.

To set up texture clamping, you can do the following:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

This will cause any pixels sampled from outside the texture to return the same color as the nearest pixel within the texture to that sample location.

Comment: Thank you! That works when if I call that after I call glActiveTexture when my program starts up (in the part where it loads the textures)

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers and comments alread pointed out, the texture sampling states will effect both the fixed function pipeline and the programmable pipeline in the same ways. I'd just like to add that in shaders, you can also completely bypass the sampling and use the GLSL [`texelFetch()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/texelFetch.xhtml) functions where you can directly access the unfiltered texels - which will basically look like `GL_NEAREST` filtering. You will also lose the wrapping functionality and hve to use unnormalized integer texture coords, so this is probably not what you want in that scenario, though.